# Byte array and int transferring between C# and C++ in Unity DLL Integration

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, unity-game-engine, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am developing a Unity project where I've created a DLL in C++ to integrate with my C# scripts. The C++ function I've written is meant to receive a byte array and its size as input parameters. However, I'm encountering an issue where the byte array and byte array length in C# is different from the data received in C++, leading to unexpected behavior.

Here's a simplified version of my C# and C++ code:

C# code

```
void OnMessageReceived(CommsMessage message) {
    byte[] frameDataByteArray = message.payload.ToByteArray();
    int frameDataLength = frameDataByteArray.Length;
    Debug.Log("Frame length in C# is: " + frameDataLength);
    byte[] output = MyCppFunction(messagePtr, frameDataLength);
}

  [DllImport("utility", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern byte[] MyCppFunction(byte[] messagePtr, int messageSize);
```

C++ code

```
cv::Mat MyCppFunction(const unsigned char* messagePtr, int messageSize) {
    std::cerr << "Received message size in C++: " << messageSize << std::endl;
    // Additional processing...
}
```

The issue arises when I print out the lengths in both C# and C++. The length in C# is correct, but the messageSize variable in C++ seems to be incorrect, showing a significantly larger value.

I'm also assuming that the byte[] I'm passing in is affected by this issue but I haven't been able to properly test it. I'm not very proficient in C++ so I'm assuming there's some obvious explanation for why the memory is getting corrupted. Also I'm going to need to receive a byte[] back from C++ to utilize in my C# script. I'm hoping the answer to the first issue will lead me to the answer for this next issue. But if you're able to help on that front too I'd be appreciative.

I suspect this could be caused by one of the following:

- Data Type Mismatch: There might be a mismatch in data types between
  C# and C++, leading to incorrect interpretation of the byte array
  size.
- Memory Management Issue: There could be a memory management issue,
  such as memory corruption or incorrect pointer usage, causing the
  size to be distorted in the C++ function.
- Endianness Problem: The discrepancy in values might be due to
  endianness differences between C# and C++ platforms.

Comment: The code above is not valid: you declare the PInvoke function as `byte[] messagePtr` but are passing an HGlobal pointer (which you aren't disposing for some reason). You don't need to marshal the array, you can just pass it directly. You are also missing `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.CDecl` on the DllImport attribute

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the comment. That was my bad, I copied some outdated code. The marshalling/using an IntPtr was residual from a previous attempt (that still didn't work). I've updated the post to my current implementation that directly passes the byte[]. I'm not using CallingConvention since I haven't seen it used in other areas of the repo, but I'll investigate that next. Does the C++ code look correct? Can byte[] from C# get correctly interpretted as an unsigned const* in C++?

Comment: Yes the parameter should work fine. The return value `cv::Mat` is unlikely to get marshalled/freed correctly though, but unclear how that is being managed. Calling convention must be set, or  you will get invalid parameters or an unbalanced stack. C/C++ use CDecl by default, although it is possible to set to StdCall (the default in C#) but that is unusual.

Comment: If you are just using c++ to call openCV, you do know there are openCV wrappers avaiable for .net?

Comment: @Charlieface does the array need to be pinned ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the calling convention as CDecl, and the return value should be `IntPtr`, as you need it to dispose the `Cv:Mat` value you are receiving

```cs
[DllImport("utility", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr MyCppFunction(byte[] messagePtr, int messageSize);
```

The array does not need to be pinned, unless it is expected that the function will use beyond the lifetime of the call. The marshaller will automatically pin it for the call itself.

Consider using a proper OpenCV managed library, if that's what you are doing.

Comment: I've made edits to my Original Post to show the changes I've made to my code based on your comments. Adding a CallingConvention specification hasn't helped or seemingly changed anything on my end. C++ and C# both still print different values for my int

Comment: You are simply doing it wrong, or not at all. You keep changing your mind as to what exactly you're doing, editing your post and then yet again in comments. Perhaps you should try posting two fully compilable projects that show the problem because passing a byte array and an int is *trivial*.

Comment: @Blindy found out the issue had to do with the return type I specified for the C++ function, as well as how I defined it in C#. In C# I had tried having the return type as "byte[]" or as "IntPtr". In C++ I tried defining the return type as "unsigned char *" and "const void*". It appeared that the C++ would have garbage values for my passed parameters if I didn't have the right combination. In the end, having the C++ function return "unsigned char *" and the C# definition return "IntPtr" enabled the parameters to pass correctly. So trivial!!

Comment: Trivial, but likely wrong. There's a reason why no well-written C function returns pointers, and that's because it becomes the implicit job of the caller to release them with the correct call or face a memory leak. How are you going to call `free` or `delete` from C#? Instead, C functions take pointers for buffers to write into as parameters, allowing the caller to decide how to allocate *and* deallocate them.

Comment: You could call the destructor https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a1b2ae166171f6a7306cf09ff67a2153f There's not much you can do if the library already returns a pointer. Either way you'd need a way of accessing the method table otherwise you can't do anything with it.